# How to connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode, it says:"Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the Organizer."

I am using my Apple Developer account. I am working on the App all by myself, I have iPhone, iPad, and Mac.

How to add a device in member center and which one should I add?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the all the information you need inside the Apple [Registering Devices Using Member Center guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW10).

If you encounter any problem you can search here on SO since there are many questions (and answer) about this topic.